# Is it safe to cut the plug off a power strip (then reattach it) in order to run it through a wall?

Tags: wiring, installation, studs

I'm trying to hide the cable for the power strip that my TV is plugged into by running it behind my drywall. However, I have to go through a stud.
I'm thinking I can probably drill a hole through the stud small enough for the quarter inch cable without opening up the wall. Still trying to work this out, but seems like an angled bit, or even a long enough bit should be able to do it. The plug on the power strip however, like most, would likely be too big to get through any hole that I would want to drill in a stud.

Question is, is it safe to either cut a power cable somewhere in the middle, or cut off the plug then rewire it or a new one in order to run the wire, then reattach the plug once it's through?

Attaching a picture in case I'm being completely unclear. FYI, the white cable in the picture is just being run to pull through whatever cable I ultimately end up running.

Open to any feedback at all on how to accomplish this, including how to get a hole drilled in that stud (though again, this seems like it should be fairly straightforward with a long enough drillbit....and yes, I plan to be very careful about not drilling through wires!!)

Thanks in advance for any help!!

[image: A picture is worth at least a couple words...]

Comment: Why not just install a proper outlet behind the TV?

Comment: @Tyson He probably doesn't realize how easy that would be to do. The hardest part is cutting holes and running cable - and he's doing that anyway.

Comment: Are you only trying to run power, or will you have to pull data/communication cables as well?

Comment: My electrician brother in law just read me the 'Riot Act' for even suggesting this strategy ... Well ... in all fairness, I was going to hard wire the power strip directly to the receptacle. He almost came through the phone ... lesson learned. It was nice to not just get the "NO !!!" ... without knowing why !!!

Answer (score 6):

This is a little unclear from the description and picture. What I **think** you are asking is:

*Can I take a power-strip that has a bunch of receptacles on one end and a 3-prong plug on the other end, chop it in half, feed it through some holes in the wall & stud, and then reattach it and plug it into a wall-mounted receptacle?*

The answer to that is **NO, that would be a big violation of code (using cable not appropriate for in-wall installation) and also not in accordance with UL (or other agency) certified use of the power strip**.

However, what you can and **should** do is:

**Feed a cable (e.g., Romex) from the receptacle down below point A to point B, connect it properly to the existing receptacle in A, mount an appropriate box in the wall at B and connect it to a receptacle in B.** Note that you've actually done some of the work already by feeding a cable (though likely not the right type, but you can use it to pull the right cable (black/white/ground)) from right next to a receptacle up to the correct level. Cut a space and mount a box to the stud at B (the stud right there will give you a proper place to attach it, and it will be easy to drill the hole before you mount the box). The cable will can be pigtailed together with the existing cable that goes to the existing, below A, receptacle and connected to the new receptacle at B.

Would the first method work OK and *probably* not cause any real problems? Yes...if the cable was spliced properly (wire nuts on wire stripped properly), nothing ever went wrong with this cable hanging out and spliced inside the wall cavity (which is also against code), nothing mounted in the future messed up the cable, nobody ever pulled on the ends wondering "what's going on here", etc. But definitely NOT a wise move.

Would it pass even the most basic electrical inspection or (hopefully) home inspector? **No.**

Comment: Suggesting that cutting a temporary use extension cord feeding it through a wall and slicing the end back on would *probably not cause any problem* is bad advice. The rest of your answer is very good.

Comment: I'll add a little more in the way of warning

Comment: Thanks for the detailed response. Makes perfect sense.

As far as wiring a new outlet, the switch at receptacle A is just a low voltage switch for the gas fireplace you can see in the bottom right.

If I'm not mistaken, there wouldn't be a way to wire the outlet I'd need to that receptacle.

Seem like the only option would be running romex all the way to the outlet on the bottom left, which would require getting wire through another stud...but could be doable. 

Does that sound about right?

Thanks again!

Comment: @ElliottSamuelLemberger Yes, that's correct. But should not be any more studs than you are already dealing with. Remove the existing surge protector and the cover plate for the receptacle. You should be able to, possibly with one more small hole (**carefully** drilled) run Romex from that receptacle to the hole you already made at the bottom then pull it up to the switch and then over through a new hole in the stud at B and mount a new box there with another receptacle. Read up - plenty elsewhere on this site or get a book. You need to be careful (and **breaker off** before doing anything)...

Comment: but really not that hard to do. You've already cut into the wall - many people freak out at that part, so you're 1/2-way there already.

Comment: Thanks @manassehkatz Seems fairly straightforward. Hardest part might be drilling holes through the studs without having to cut open the drywall. Any tips on drilling sideways? :)

Comment: Code would require the hole through the stud to be 1-1/4" back from the face of the stud.

Comment: @EdBeal Thank you. That's the type of detail that I (coming from a low-voltage computer/phone wiring/DIY background) don't know.

Comment: @ElliottSamuelLemberger In the case of the bottom next to the existing receptacle, if there is a stud in between where you cut and the receptacle then you should already have a clean shot at it. For "B", once you open up that little hole in the drywall to the size of the box you're going to mount next to the stud, you will have plenty of room there too. Best solution is a really long drill bit.

Comment: Thanks again everyone! So basically I'd be looking at an angled hole through each stud, since at best I'd probably be able to hit each one at a  45 degree angle. Any issues with an angled hole through the studs vs straight on? (not that I really have much choice) I'll be sure to clear at least 1-1/4" from edge, thanks for the tip @EdBeal BTW, I didn't actually cut out that bottom hole...there was already a j box there I think for an old coax or something. The only hole I made was the small one up top. But with all your help and guidance I think I can do this! Thanks again!!

Answer (score 1):

First, you know they make kits to solve the problem of hiding TV cables. They carry power legally and also provide a wide passage for datacomm cables, properly separated from power as per Code.

Typically they provide an outlet at the TV and a power inlet which a female end of an extension cord.

You can also wire your own receptacles using permanent wiring methods intended for a building. That can tie directly into power, or go to an inlet, as you prefer.

Embedding a power cord of any kind in a wall is right out. Also low voltage cables must be completely separate from 
power cables.

Answer (score 1):

To get a hole through the stud, you'll want to use a [flexible drill bit](https://www.kleintools.com/catalog/flex-bit-accessories/flex-bit-kit) and positioning tool.

[image: Flexible drill bit kit]

Once you have the path. You'll want to use approved wiring methods to get power from the existing receptacle, to the new receptacle behind the TV.  This means running non-metallic sheathed cable (NM) (or similar), from the existing receptacle, into a proper device box behind the TV. Once you have the cable there, you can install a receptacle in the device box behind the TV.

If you'll also want to run data/communications cables, from a similar location up to the TV.  I'd recommend installing flexible conduit from end to end, to make it easier to swap out cables as needed.  You'll have to keep data and power separate, which will mean drilling a second hole through the stub.

> ## WARNING!!!
>
> You **CANNOT** install extension cords through walls. You must use approved wires/cables, and approved wiring methods.